# I can't run C# on visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

i worked on Visual studio a long time (mainly on java and on python) i tried to use C# and when i am running the code it asks me to select an environment, there are two options after that ".Net Frameworkd 4.x (windows only)" and "Ionide Launchsetting". the first does nothing and the second opend a file setting.json
`

```
{
  "java.home": "C:\\Users\\Public\\wpilib\\2022\\jdk",
  "extensions.autoUpdate": false,
  "extensions.autoCheckUpdates": false,
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
  "extensions.showRecommendationsOnlyOnDemand": false,
  "update.channel": "none",
  "update.showReleaseNotes": false,
  "http.systemCertificates": false,
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\Public\\wpilib\\2022\\jdk",
    "PATH": "C:\\Users\\Public\\wpilib\\2022\\jdk\\bin;${env:PATH}"
  },
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "C_Cpp.addNodeAddonIncludePaths": true
}
```

`

i tried using dotnet new console but it didn't word, it opened some files but it changed nothing when i tried running C#

Comment: VS Code and Visual Studio are completely different products. What you posted here isn't a Visual Studio config file. Ionide isn't used in Visual Studio at all. VS Code is a language agnostic IDE, you need to actually install support for specific languages. VS itself is equivalent to Eclipse and NetBeans, a full-featured IDE. You specify the type of workloads (projects) to include right in the setup process (desktop, web, data science etc)

Comment: If you haven't worked with C# before, install Visual Studio, not VS Code